# Javascript Dynamically added HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Please Look at the following code only the last image moves. 
http://jsfiddle.net/u8Bg3/

But second one  works
http://jsfiddle.net/u8Bg3/1/

As pointed by the Er144 even this works with jquery 
http://jsfiddle.net/u8Bg3/14/

I also found out appendchild works but not innerhtml

The difference between two is that in first one html exits in second one it's dynamically created

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="racetrack" id="racetrack"></div>
    <div id="track-tmpl" class="hide">
        <div class="track"><div id="player{{ x }}" class="runner"></div></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
var position = [0,40,80,120,80],
    racetrack = document.getElementById('racetrack');
    track_tmpl = document.getElementById('track-tmpl').innerHTML;


function Players(ele, ptimeout)
{
    this.el = ele;
    this.i = 0;
    this.iterations = 0;
    this.stop = 0;
    this.timeout = ptimeout;
    this.position = 0;

    this.animate = function(){
        if(this.i !== 0){
            this.move((this.position + 5), this.i);
        }
        if(!this.stop){
            if(this.i < 5){
                setTimeout(function(_this){             
                    _this.i++;
                    _this.animate();
                },this.timeout,this);
            }
            if(this.i==5){
                this.iterations ++;
                if(this.iterations < 50){
                    this.i = 0;
                    this.animate();
                }
                else{
                    this.el.style.backgroundPosition = '120px 0px';
                }
            }
        }
    };


    this.start = function(){
        this.stop = 0;
        this.animate();
    };

    this.move = function(to,positionIndex){
        this.position = to;
        this.el.style.backgroundPosition = '-'+position[positionIndex]+'px 0px';
        this.el.style.webkitTransform = 'translate('+to+'px)';
        this.el.style.mozTransform = 'translate('+to+'px)';
    }
}

function Game(noOfPlayers){

    this.noOfPlayers = noOfPlayers;

    this.players = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < this.noOfPlayers ; i++){
        racetrack.innerHTML = racetrack.innerHTML + track_tmpl.replace('{{ x }}', i);
        this.players.push(new Players(document.getElementById('player' + i), (120 + i)));
        /* issue here with dynamic added content*/
    }


    this.start = function(){
        for (var i = 0; i < this.noOfPlayers; i++){
            this.players[i].start();
        }
    };
}

var game = new Game(3);
game.start();
```

**Why is that in dynamically added html only the last one moves**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with creating the `player(n)` object inside the for loop along with the assignments to innerHTML using `+='. The modified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u8Bg3/15/ works fine. Cheers for a good question!

```
  var finalized_tracks= "" ;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.noOfPlayers ; i++){
    finalized_tracks +=  track_tmpl.replace('{{ x }}', i);
    }
  racetrack.innerHTML = racetrack.innerHTML + finalized_tracks;

    for (var i = 0; i < this.noOfPlayers ; i++){
  this.players.push(new Players(document.getElementById('player'+ i),(120+i)));
    }
```

Comment: but why... is this so

Answer (score 0):

If you use the jquery:

```
var element = track_tmpl.replace('{{ x }}', i);
$(racetrack).append(element);
```

instead of the line where you change the innerHtml of racetrack div, all elements are moving.
However, I'm not sure, why...

Answer (score 0):

theCoder has pretty much nailed the issue with your code there.

Just as an additional thought, you could manually build the necessary divs using javascript instead, it's more long winded however...

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.noOfPlayers ; i++){
    var newTrack = document.createElement("div");
        newTrack.id = "track"+i;
        newTrack.className = "track";

        var newPlayer = document.createElement("div");
        newPlayer.id = "player"+i;
        newPlayer.className = "runner";

        newTrack.appendChild(newPlayer);
        racetrack.appendChild(newTrack);

        this.players.push(new Players(document.getElementById('player' + i), (120 + i)));
}
```